# Storing elements of array entered one by one, to be displayed altogether later

Tags: java, arrays, loops, switch-statement, element

Thanks for the help so far. I am making a menu in java, the first option requires the user to enter a number and have it added to an array, after entering the number, they have to choose option 1 again to enter the next number to be added to the array, they cannot be added all at once, this needs to happen up to 5 times.
My code is only storing the most recent number given and displaying it when I select option 2:
[image of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnKXM.png)

Is there a way I can add and store each element to the array one by one and then display all that was input altogether when I select option 2 from my switch statement?

```
            //Menu loop
            int myMonths[] = new int[5];
            while(choice !=6){

                switch (choice){
                case 1:
                //int n = number of projects
                int n=1;
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("How many months was your project?");
                for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                    //read the elements of the array
                    myMonths[i]=sc.nextInt();}
                break;
                case 2:

                System.out.println("Choice 2: Display all items");
                for(int i=0; i < myMonths.length; i++){
                    System.out.println(myMonths[i] + " ");}
                break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only assigning one project outside of the loop. By the time you ask them, the length of the for-loop is only **int n = 1**

```
            //int n = number of projects
            int n=1;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("How many months was your project?");
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)   // THIS IS LIKE i < 1
            {
                //read the elements of the array
                myMonths[i]=sc.nextInt();
            }
```

Comment: When I change n to the max number of projects that I want stored in the array, it only allows me to put them in all at once. My requirement is for it to exit case 1 with the item stored in the array, and allow me to again choose case 1 and add another one. Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: Keeping an index variable outside of the loop seems like the right move; with index++ you are both calling the array at that index and increasing its value by 1

Comment: //This is my Psuedocode approach
**int index = 0;
while(choice != 6)
{
 myMonths[index++] = sc.nextInt();
}**

Comment: That did it!!! Thank you so so much, I've been stuck on this two days now haha. You've been such a help

Comment: Right on! You are more than welcome; I'm glad you got it working :D